# Passing an ID and String array to Spring MVC via jQuery/ajax+JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, spring-mvc

I need to POST a request via jQuery.ajax() to a Spring MVC controller URL mapped method and receive a response; both request and response data is in JSON format.

Ajax call would be something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/panelsData",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { "id": 1, "panels": [ "View1", "View2", "View3" ] },
    success: function(data) {...}
});
```

Spring MVC controller URL mapped method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/panelsData", method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public List<PanelData> getPanelsDataById(
         @RequestParam("id") BigDecimal id,
         @RequestParam("panels") List<String> panelsList) {

    // Process list of Strings corresponding to panel view names
    // and return a list of PanelData objects (in JSON format).
}
```

The first problem I faced was that the client (browser) failed with error code 400 (Bad Request). So, I JSON.stringify'ed the array in the ajax call:

```
data: { "id": 1, "panels": JSON.stringify([ "View1", "View2", "View3" ]) },
```

This time, the request was successfully received by Spring MVC. But something was amiss with the list of String values. When I examined the values, here's what I saw:

```
panelsList[0] = ""[View1""
panelsList[1] = ""View2""
panelsList[2] = ""View3]""
```

What?! I was expecting these values:

```
panelsList[0] = "View1"
panelsList[1] = "View2"
panelsList[2] = "View3"
```

Am I incorrectly serializing (or de-serializing) the values? Given that the exchange of data must all be JSON, and that I am using the Jackson library, I was expecting that receiving an ID and a list of String values from the client in JSON should not be all that difficult. I know the Jackson library configuration is perfect, because the JSON responses returned by the other methods are correctly formed.

Comment: You have to understand the first and the very important thing if you are passing a data from json, you have the same type and patterns of data....like as here I'm creating method signature on basis of json data  public PanelData getPanelsDataById( @RequestParam("id") BigDecimal id, @RequestParam("panels") List<String> panelsList)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be better if you can restructure your code something like below.

rather than passing/receiving them in separate argument,you can create PanelDataJson class,which contains both id and list of panel.

```
class PanelDataJson{
    BigDecimal id;
    List<String> panelsList;

     //Getter and Setter

}
```

And then change your method like below.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/panelsData", method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public List<PanelData> getPanelsDataById(
         @RequestBody PanelDataJson) {

    // Process list of Strings corresponding to panel view names
    // and return a list of PanelData objects (in JSON format).
}
```

And from your front end,just stringify your whole data,not partially.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/panelsData",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ "id": 1, "panels": [ "View1", "View2", "View3" ] }),
    type: "POST",
    contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function(data) {...}
});
```

Comment: If I absolutely did not want to create a new class, the following also worked for me - to the Ajax call's options, add `traditional: true` and for the data option, `data: $.param({ "id": 1, "panels": [ "View1", "View2", "View3" ] }, true)`.

Comment: Very helpful @WebUser , Thanks a lot for this approach as well as question. I wanted to ask one thing, is setting "traditional:true" , harmful or insecure?